# Spring Boot livereload without losing user session data

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is it possible to use Spring Boot WITH livereload in a way that, when Java code is updated and it recompiles, it still maintains the session data?

What's happening now is, I have to re-login EVERY TIME I change Java code.

I am currently using hash-store and I understand that this is wiped each time the Java livereloads... can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: You might use application listeners to persist session on app passivate or destroy events and retrieve session on app init events.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to run the Spring Boot app using the [spring-loaded](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded) jar as the jvm Java agent. It's sort of an improved version of hotswap, that would apply code changes to classes in the class path automatically.